# Game Maker studio: When I run the game

Tags: html, gml

After I loaded the game up I get this error message below

I loaded the game back up and though it worked again because my slime enemy are still moving around the game but when I left clicked the mouse, my game just freezes and I have to end up exiting out the game.

I went to game maker community website page and see others with the same issue as I did, but most people said it's something with game maker studio's file > preferences and on the window's tab I see the location.

I pressed check windows SDK button and though it worked because I see status shows Visual studio is OK. I though that worked any ideas?

```
// In Script scr_check_for_player at line 1 : unknown function or script instance_exist 

// In Script scr_enemy_choose_next_state at line 3 : wrong number of arguments for function irandom 

// In Script scr_enemy_choose_next_state at line 3 : malformed assignment statement 

// Compile Failed - Please check the Compile window for any additional information
```

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, the game maker function `instance_exist` is actually `instance_exists`, try that and see if it is correct. Also, search for the arguments in the function `irandom` and apply it correctly.